# VS Code - Drag image from Explorer pane into markdown file and drop as path

Tags: path, drag-and-drop, visual-studio-code, png, markdown

In Visual Studio Code, from the Explorer pane, how can I drag a PNG file from my images folder and drop it in place in a markdown file, so that VS Code inserts the path to the dropped image?

Currently, VS Code just opens the image in a new tab.

I've reviewed the suggested answers, as well as the available markdown extensions, with no luck finding an answer.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I've looked it up everywhere too, bharath is entirely correct, for now you could just use right click -> copy path and paste it, It's quite tedious compared to a drag and drop solution, but Hopefully there would be an asset for that, If someone made this: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mushan.vscode-paste-image

definitely something similar for just dragging and dropping would be possible

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is not possible yet in `vscode` as compared to `visual studio`. There seems to be a pending feature request on their GitHub issues page (link below) which was opened long back and not yet closed.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5240

Answer (score 2):

It should be in vscode v1.67 - it is in the Insiders Build now.

And see the v1.67 Release Notes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_67.md#markdown-drop-into-editor-to-create-link:

> You can now quickly create markdown links by dragging and dropping
> files from VS Code's explorer into a markdown editor. Simply hold
> `Shift` while dragging the file over a markdown editor to drop it into
> the editor and create a link to it:
>
> If the file looks like an image, we will automatically insert an
> markdown image. Otherwise we add a normal markdown link.
>
> This also works when dragging some types of files from other
> applications, such as dragging and dropping images from a web browser:

[image: drop image as a link into a markdown file]

1. enable `Workbench > Editor > Drop Into Editor: Enabled`

That allows you to <kbd>Shift</kbd> drag an image file into an editor without opening a new editor of that image.

2. enable `Markdown > Editor > Drop: Enabled`

[image: drag and drop an image into markdown to get a link]

---

Also see [v1.68 Release Notes, pasting an image or file to create a link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_68.md#paste-files-to-insert-markdown-links):

> #### Paste files to insert Markdown links
>
> We've added experimental support pasting to insert images or file
> links in markdown.
>
> This requires enabling `"editor.experimental.pasteActions.enabled": true`. You can currently copy files from the VS Code explorer. Pasting
> image files inserts image references while pasting normal text files
> inserts links to those files.

Comment: I'm glad they made the feature built-in. For some reason my "relative" path that gets inserted starts with ![Alt text](../../../../../../../C:/Users/longPathToGetToImage/image.png)

Comment: why pressing `shift`? why not just drag and drop?

Comment: @Alex The `shift` is necessary if you want a link - otherwise vscode simply opens an editor with the file you dropped - that has worked that way for a long time and I don't think they want to change it.

Answer (score -4):

subject: If you want an image in any folder of your vscode.
simply follow the steps.
1.Go to vscode then right click on a folder in which you want your image and then choose reveal in file explorer. After that you can simply copy your image into the vs code folder.